Почему во Flutter через Firebase notification не получаю сообщение в android приложении в фоновом режиме
D/FLTFireMsgReceiver( 5400): broadcast received for message
W/m.example.pulse( 5400): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(I)Z (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.pulse( 5400): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->add(ILjava/lang/String;)Z (unsupported,test-api, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.pulse( 5400): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->get(I)I (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/m.example.pulse( 5400): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/WorkSource;->getName(I)Ljava/lang/String; (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/FirebaseMessaging( 5400): Unable to log event: analytics library is missing
W/FirebaseMessaging( 5400): Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.

Получаю такой ответ
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:label="pulse"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"/>

            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
                android:resource="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
                android:value="default_notification_channel_id"/>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService"            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2"/>
    </application>

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

Вот мой AndroidManifest.xml
вот входной файл
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

import 'firebase_options.dart';

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  const AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
      AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

  const InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
      InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  _showNotification(message);
}

void _showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'high_importance_channel',
    'High Importance Notifications',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
    showWhen: true,
  );
  const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    message.notification?.title,
    message.notification?.body,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'item x',
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? _token;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _registerOnFirebase();

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
        _showNotification(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void _registerOnFirebase() {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((token) {
      setState(() {
        _token = token;
      });
      print("Firebase Messaging Token: $_token");
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.instance.onTokenRefresh.listen((newToken) {
      setState(() {
        _token = newToken;
      });
      print("Firebase Messaging New Token: $_token");
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('FCM Token Example'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text(_token == null ? 'Loading token...' : 'Token: $_token'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Кажется нужно добавить тег на уровне application в AndroidManifest:
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="com.domain.appname.urgent" />

Вместо com.domain.appname.urgent нужно написать своё значение.
